# iOS what is the best way to notify user about event in geofence?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, ios6, gps

Problem is discussed bellow :

1: User can register multiple events using my app with trigger distance and address.

how can i fire multiple events on the basis of location , when user near by , or leave or cross the registered event place .

where i have to manage the events and alert him.

i am using CLLocationManger delegate method didUpdateLocation for trace the location distance

please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS native support for Location is expansively explained in [Location Awareness Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/Introduction/Introduction.html). As you go through it, you will see that your `didUpdateLocation` is nothing but a step in tracking user's location.

That said, there are number of other steps involved:

1. `[locationManager startUpdatingLocation]` - Triggers Location Manager to start monitoring for location updates.
2. `didUpdateLocations` - Delegate to be notified about location updates. Note that your method `didUpdateLocation` is valid for versions < iOS 6.
3. `[locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges]` - fires location update events so that accurate monitoring is available with good power savings.
4. [Region monitoring](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW8) - this is what you want for geofence requirement.

   - `regionMonitoringAvailable` decides if hardware supports monitoring shape based regions.
   - `startMonitoringForRegion` method starts monitoring a specific region.
   - Similarly, `stopMonitoringForRegion` stops monitoring for a region.
   - Finally, [didEnterRegion](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/CLLocationManagerDelegate/CLLocationManagerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007124-CH3-SW10) and [didExitRegion](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/CLLocationManagerDelegate/CLLocationManagerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007124-CH3-SW11) gives you the geofence triggering you want.

That said, there are number of third party iOS sdk providers who provide high level support for region monitoring inside your iOS app. [Geoloqi](https://developers.geoloqi.com/) and [Parse](https://parse.com) are two of them. You can visit their api pages to know more about how simplistic or complex their monitoring is, and choose based on pricing,complexity etc.

Comment: :Actually i have n number of events with there different-different latitude & longitude, now how can i manage these all , where i have to keep all events to monitor distance and alert to user.In side didLocationupdate or any where else..please clear my doubt..

Comment: See if this helps (if it does mark the answer as correct using checkmark): http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Regions/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010726

Comment: Suppose i register my events with region  ,then how came i know that user reached his location and alert him via local notification

Comment: didUpdateLocations will fire every time user significantly changes his location. Within that, it's up to you how you want to handle it. didEnterRegion and didExitRegion will serve similar purpose. While inside those functions, you can post local notifications. Notification programming is a separate subject and you should read this guide to get started: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/Articles/Posting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000724-97609-BAJCFBBI

Comment: Glad to help. Stackoverflow is the best place to help people as well as showcase one's talent. Just by phrasing your question in the right manner you will get much needed assistance, I am sure. I am afraid I am not available for Skype assistance unless for any paid time. Sorry :-(

Answer (score 0):

Nirav gave you a good overview whats included in the API, i concentrate here more on the things you will not find in apple docu:

To detect enter and leave of a geographical area, you can use
Circles, Rectangles and closed Polygons.

You store them with the latitude, longitude coordinates of that geo area.

To detect enter event:
if current location state changes from outside to inside area.

To detect leave event:
if current location state changes from inside to outside area.

```
calculate inside:
```

Inside Polygon: search here on Stackoverflow for point in polygon algorithm
Inside Rectangle: use API
Inside Circle: use API: distance from location to circle center < radius

Comment: :How can i distinguish multiple events .i am not use any type of circle & rectangle .

Comment: You only want to use multiple Polygons? assign each polygon an id. then you have an EnterEvent(id)